# Installing packages and other client libraries

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Sorry for the repeated query, but someone pointed out that my question was very vague. My question is basically how do I go about installing all the wonderful software and packages available on ros.org into ROS on my system. I am using the latest version of ROS Diamondback on Mac OS X 10.5. Furthermore, I would like to know how to install the various client libraries that are available for ROS (is it a different procedure to install them, if so how?)

Thanks,
S.

> I would like to install and use
> [roslua](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslua).
> I've read through some of the
> documentation (not all, so I might've
> not come across it yet), but I am not
> sure how to install roslua in my ros
> system. That actually goes for any
> client library or package that I like
> to install.to install.

Thanks,
S.to install.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9484/installing-packages-and-other-client-libraries/) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-28**:
how about https://github.com/timn/roslua/blob/master/README ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu, some packages are installable via Ubuntu packages (i.e., apt-get, synaptic), so you could try that first.  If no Ubuntu package is available, you can download the source from the repository, put it in a subdirectory of your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and compile with with rosmake.  That's generally all you need to do.

---

Originally posted by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) with karma: 181 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-22**:
Yes all packages work this way, including client libraries.

**Comment by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) on 2011-03-22**:
I suppose so, but I'm guessing at least roscpp and rospy will be installed by default if you install in any typical way.

**Comment by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on 2011-03-22**:
Does this go for client libraries as well?